# How do you send parameters to the mapper function in mapreduce on Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, mapreduce, google-app-engine-python

I'm trying to figure out how to use the [mapreduce library](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-mapreduce/) with the DatastoreInputReader on App Engine. I have had a lot of help from this excellent tutorial: https://sookocheff.com/post/appengine/mapreduce/programmatic-mapreduce/

But there's one thing I can't find any examples of - how do you send custom parameters to the mapper function? It seems like it only receives the entity. What if I also want to access some other data relevant to the job? For example, if I have a game and want to set everyone's score to a specific value, can I send that in somewhere? Or do I have to create a separate mapper function for every value I want to use, like this?

```
def mapper_10(user):
    user.score = 10
    user.put()

def mapper_50(user):
    user.score = 50
    user.put()
```

This looks very silly, obviously. Is there no way to do something like this?

```
def mapper(user, new_score):
    user.score = new_score
    user.put()
```

Or do I have to create my own input reader for that?

Comment: This seems to be covered in the tutorial you link to, surely. There's a `params` dict in the pipeline which seems to be exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was possible, but a bit more tricky than I thought. While you can't receive parameters to the method, you can send in parameters to the pipeline and then fetch them through the mapreduce context.

```
from mapreduce import context

def mapper(user):
    user.score = ctx.mapreduce_spec.mapper.params['new_score']
    user.put()
```

Problem solved!